How to integrate MarketingCloudSDK to a capacitor/ionic app
Hi was trying to add the sdk to a capacitor made app to integrate pushNotifications. I have already integrated that app with firebase and works fine but i have no idea how to integrate that solution to with marketing cloud sdk. I have read the documentation of Marketing cloud but i have no clue how to implement that into the capacitor app. Does anyone has integrated the marketingcloudsdk with a capacitor/ionic app ?
i tried to do what the marketing cloud documentation says but is no use
